# fullscreen in flash document resized after open another program?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fullscreen

I create a flash interface for CD that contains some buttons that open some word documents.I use fscommand for open files.

`fscommand("exec", "documnet.doc");`

But after document open the flash document resized from fullscreen.

the Question is: How I can make flash document (swf or exe) still fullscreen after focusing another program or open another program?

Comment: What is the flash document running in, a browser, air? can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: No, in a desktop. and I'll edit my qustion to be more clear. thatnks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add an event listener to the stage. So, when the stage is activated you will reenter full screen mode. Try this code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, 
  function(event:Event) { 
    trace("Enter full screen");  
  } 
);
```

You may choose another events that more suitable to your project from [list of events dispatched by the 'stage' object](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html). (Don't forget to show all inherited events.